# Probability: Not Equally Likely Outcomes.

Tags: probability

The basic definition of Probability of a particular event is given by:

$$\frac{\text{No. of favorable outcomes}}{\text{Total no. of outcomes}} $$

Is this valid if the outcomes are equally likely? If not then why?

Comment: It is valid **if** if the outcomes are equiprobable. If they are not then it might not be valid. Throw a die that is not unbiased.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  As you say, it's a definition (at least under the assumption that all events are equally probable).  What are you asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only valid if all the outcomes are equally likely.  Another way to say this is that this is valid if and only if the probability of all of the outcomes are the same value.

If the probability of the outcomes differ, then the equation must be altered as follows.

$\text{Probability}(\text{event}) = \sum_{\text{favorable events}} \text{Probability}(i^{\text{th}}\text{ favorable event})$.

For example, suppose you wanted to know the probability of an even number on a six sided fair die.  Then this could be determine as 3/6 since there are 3 even numbers and 6 total numbers.

But now, what if you wanted the probability of an even number or a 5?  We already know that the probability of an even number is 1/2.  And the probability of a 5 is 1/6.  So the probability of an even number or a 5 is 1/2 + 1/6 = 2/3.